# Как правильно использовать SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-shared-preferences

У меня есть класс, в котором описывается работа с SharedPreferences:

```
class TextPreferences(context: Context) {

    private val PREFS_FILENAME = TextPreferences::class.java.simpleName
    val TEXT = "TEXT" 
    private var pref: SharedPreferences? = null

    fun getText(): String? {
        return pref?.getString(TEXT, null)
    }

    fun setText(res: String) {
        val editor = pref?.edit()
        editor?.putString(TEXT, res)
        editor?.apply()
    }

    init {
        pref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            PREFS_FILENAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
    }
}
```

В одном из классов я устанавливаю значение для Preferences методом setText(), а в остальных классах (их  порядка десяти), нужно извлечь это значение, методом getText().

Код фрагмента, в котором извлекается значение TextPreferences:

```
class MyFragment: BaseFragment() {
    
    private var prefs: TextPreferences? = null
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            prefs = TextPreferences(requireActivity().baseContext)
    
            val someString = prefs?.getText()
    }
}
```

Вопрос в том, правильно ли я работаю с Preferences? Правильно ли в каждом классе создавать по объекту типа TextPreferences, чтобы извлечь из него значение? А если надо будет в 1000 классах извлечь значение, то ведь придётся создать 1000 таких объектов. Может я не правильно что-то понимаю?

Comment: 1000 классов это очень много, если у вас будет столько активностей/фрагментов то нужно будет пересматривать архитектуру проекта а не логику получения данных. А по поводу получения данных - вам что так что этак нужно получить доступ к хранилищу, вы просто используя класс уменьшаете кол-во кода и точек входа которые нужно поддерживать

Comment: Может быть, можно организовать `Singleton`? Где сохраняете текст в `SharedPreferences`, там сохраняйте его в поле своего `Singleton`, тогда можно будет получить значение без вызова `pref?.getString`

Comment: @Andrew т.е. я правильно делаю, что создаю объект TextPreferences в каждом классе, получается?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов я думал об этом, но пока не знаю, как это реализовать, с Singleton'ами не работал ещё...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делаю следующим образом.
Создаю `Extension`-функции:

```
fun SharedPreferences.putAny(key: String, any: Any) {
  when (any) {
    is String -> edit { putString(key, any) }
    is Int -> edit { putInt(key, any) }
  }
}

fun SharedPreferences.getAny(type: Any, key: String) = when (type) {
  is String -> getString(key, "") as Any
  else -> getInt(key, 0)
}
```

А `SharedPreferences` инжекчу с помощью `Koin` во `ViewModel` или во `Fragment`

```
preferences.putAny(TOKEN, "")
val lat = preferences.getAny("", LATITUDE) as String
```

Comment: Спасибо! А вместо Koin'а можно dagger использовать?

Comment: Да конечно. Любой di-фреймворк